# unable to compile PgAdmin3

Tags: visual-studio-2013, postgresql-9.2, pgadmin

these errors are coming when compiling in release and X64..

> Error  320 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol xsltCleanupGlobals referenced in function "private: class wxString __cdecl frmReport::XslProcessReport(class wxString const &,class wxString const &)" (?XslProcessReport@frmReport@@AEAA?AVwxString@@AEBV2@0@Z)  C:\Newfolder\pgadmin3-1.20.0\pgadmin\frmReport.obj  pgAdmin3
>
> Error  321 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol xsltFreeStylesheet referenced in function "private: class wxString __cdecl frmReport::XslProcessReport(class wxString const &,class wxString const &)" (?XslProcessReport@frmReport@@AEAA?AVwxString@@AEBV2@0@Z)  C:\Newfolder\pgadmin3-1.20.0\pgadmin\frmReport.obj  pgAdmin3
>
> Error  322 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol xsltParseStylesheetDoc referenced in function "private: class wxString __cdecl frmReport::XslProcessReport(class wxString const &,class wxString const &)" (?XslProcessReport@frmReport@@AEAA?AVwxString@@AEBV2@0@Z)  C:\Newfolder\pgadmin3-1.20.0\pgadmin\frmReport.obj  pgAdmin3
>
> Error  323 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol xsltApplyStylesheet referenced in function "private: class wxString __cdecl frmReport::XslProcessReport(class wxString const &,class wxString const &)" (?XslProcessReport@frmReport@@AEAA?AVwxString@@AEBV2@0@Z) C:\Newfolder\pgadmin3-1.20.0\pgadmin\frmReport.obj  pgAdmin3
>
> Error  324 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol xsltSaveResultToString referenced in function "private: class wxString __cdecl frmReport::XslProcessReport(class wxString const &,class wxString const &)" (?XslProcessReport@frmReport@@AEAA?AVwxString@@AEBV2@0@Z)  C:\Newfolder\pgadmin3-1.20.0\pgadmin\frmReport.obj  pgAdmin3
>
> Error  325 error LNK1120: 5 unresolved externals   C:\Newfolder\pgadmin3-1.20.0\pgadmin\Release\pgAdmin3.exe   pgAdmin3

added linker settings and also vc++ directory settings still the above errors are coming. please do needful, to generate pgAdmin3.exe in release folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above error is because of linking an invalid libxslt.lib file, it got fixed by changing that linked libxslt.lib to correct 64bit file.